# remove some initial bytes from a bytearray in flex

Tags: apache-flex, arrays

I read a file's content into a byte array using the following code:

```
  public var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
  var primaryfile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("data/updates/assets/"+this.assetvideoid+"/"+this.assetdetails[0]['filename']);
  var tempfile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("data/updates/assets/"+this.assetvideoid+"/"+this.assetdetails[0]['filename']+"-temp");
  filestream = new FileStream();
  filestream.open(primaryfile, FileMode.READ);
  filestream.readBytes(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
  filestream.close();
```

Is it possible to remove some initial bytes from a bytearray say 30 bytes from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filestream.open(primaryfile, FileMode.READ);
filestream.readBytes(bytes, 30, bytes.length - 30);
filestream.close();
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore the first 30 bytes of the file, you could change the arguments in [`readBytes`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#readBytes%28%29) as follows:

```
  filestream.readBytes(bytes, 30, 0);
```

note that `bytes.length` will be zero since there is nothing in it initially.